# I have a frame with an image in it and i am trying to add a JComponent over it

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried a few different ways of doing this but all have failed.

Currently I have a frame with an image set in it using a class called backViewer that extends JPanel. I would like to take that frame and place a JComponent over it that I can then move. The background image will appear but the JComponent, SchellTower, will not appear over top of it.

```js
package Graphical;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.accessibility.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;


public class TowerViewer extends JFrame {


  public TowerViewer() {
    //backViewer
    /*public class backViewer extends JPanel {
 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponents(g);
  Image image = new ImageIcon("filename").getImage();
  g.drawImage(image,0,0,500,690,null);
  
 }*/
    setSize(500, 688);
    backViewer back = new backViewer();
    add(back);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Schell Tower");

  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TowerViewer t = new TowerViewer();
    SchellTower comp = new SchellTower();
    t.add(comp);
    t.setVisible(true);

    //moving the component this works on its own and seems to be running in the back ground 
    //but the SchellTower component isnt visible 
    int x = 0;
    while (true) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        comp.move(0, x);
        t.add(comp);
        x += 60;
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000); //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
      try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
      x -= 60;
      for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
        comp.move(0, x);
        t.add(comp);
        x -= 60;
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000); //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm willing to try anything at this point thanks in advance

Comment: use swing timer  and call `repaint()` `revalidate()` after add

Comment: are you just saying to add t.repaint(); and t.revalidate(); after add(comp). The background image is still the only image to appear.

Comment: try add layout like flowLayout  to TowerViewer.use setLayout method

Comment: I have tried different Layouts using setLayout(new layout) but that hasn't helped. what is and how do I use this use method

Comment: what is the class `SchellTower comp = new SchellTower();` could you post this class also .

Comment: SChellTower was a class that extended JCOmponent and used the method PaintComponent to draw an image of a tower.

Comment: I figured it out by adding t.setComponentZOrder(comp, 0); after the add statement

Answer (score 0):

Adding t.setComponentZOrder(component, index) after adding the component to the frame placed the component above the background

```js
final TowerViewer t = new TowerViewer(); //a frame with a background image already set
  SchellTower comp = new SchellTower();
  t.add(comp);
  t.setComponentZOrder(comp, 0); //this line places image above background
  t.setVisible(true);
```